# SQL ERROR: 1066 not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1066

Hi I'm stuck on this query

`SELECT c1.ID
FROM cliente JOIN corsa AS c1 ON corsa.cliente_ID = cliente.ID_cliente,
     cliente JOIN corsa AS c2 ON corsa.cliente_ID =  cliente.ID_cliente
WHERE c1.tariffa = c2.tariffa AND c2.ID_cliente = 1 AND c2.data_corsa = "2012-06-20";`

I get error 1066 not unique table/alias: 'cliente'.
I understood there is a problem in the FROM statement in which I call 'cliente' twice. I just can't figure out how to make it work.

I tried this

`SELECT DISTINCT c1.*
FROM cliente INNER JOIN corsa AS c1,
     cliente c2 INNER JOIN corsa AS c3
WHERE c1.tariffa = c3.tariffa AND c3.cliente_ID = 1 AND c3.data_corsa = "2012-06-20";`

and it seems to work, but I'm not so sure of it.

Thanks

Comment: `c1 ON corsa.cliente_ID` should be `c1 ON c1.cliente_ID` and `c2 ON corsa.cliente_ID` should be `c2 ON c2.cliente_ID `

Comment: It does not solve the error 1066 :/